# Q: Can TWO different ARUCO 7X7_1000 images render the same ID?

Tags: opencv, aruco

While reading about a nice precise UAV landing approach (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Example-of-e-ArUco-marker-based-on-a-7x7-sized-ArUco-marker-The-inner-marker-is-located_fig4_351864208) I was wondering, how the inner Aruco code cannot confuse the detection of the outer Aruco code. I was experimenting a bit and covering the inner Aruco code with a black and then a white pad. In both cases the detected ID was 29. I'm now looking for an explanation for this "phenomenon"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's *redundancy* for *error correction*.

The academic discipline is called [Coding theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory)

The same idea is used in QR codes to put pictures in them.

[The original ArUco paper](https://cs-courses.mines.edu/csci507/schedule/24/ArUco.pdf) talks about the the coding scheme they chose. Their website: https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26